# With Web Audio API, is it possible to turn off speaker's volume, but input is still alive

Tags: jquery, html, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to record human voice from laptop's microphone with Web Audio API.

Recording is OK.

But there is a problem that voice streams from speakers. So when recording, I hear what I say at same time.

I'm finding the way to avoid this problem. Help me! Thanks.

Comment: Please add some code snippet of what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to turn off audio streams, post the piece of code you're using to do it.

Answer (score 2):

below spins up a Web Audio API session with browser volume widget so just slide the volume down ... Web Audio API is node centric ... instead of directly connecting the `audioContext` with the microphone I introduce `gain_node` as an intermediary

```
    gain_node = audioContext.createGain();
    gain_node.connect( audioContext.destination );

    microphone_stream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    microphone_stream.connect(gain_node); 

    script_processor_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER, 1, 1);
    script_processor_node.onaudioprocess = process_microphone_buffer;

    microphone_stream.connect(script_processor_node);
```

to enable volume control for output speakers I define a callback to that gain_node

```
    document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function() {

        var curr_volume = this.value;
        gain_node.gain.value = curr_volume;

        console.log("curr_volume ", curr_volume);
    });
```

here is all of above bundled into a self contained html file

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>capture microphone then show time & frequency domain output</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var webaudio_tooling_obj = function () {

    var audioContext = new AudioContext();

    console.log("audio is starting up ...");

    var BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER = 16384;
    var SIZE_SHOW = 3; // number of array elements to show in console output

    var audioInput = null,
    microphone_stream = null,
    gain_node = null,
    script_processor_node = null,
    script_processor_analysis_node = null,
    analyser_node = null;

    if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia){

        navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, 
            function(stream) {
                start_microphone(stream);
            },
            function(e) {
                alert('Error capturing audio.');
            }
            );

    } else { alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); }

    // ---

    function show_some_data(given_typed_array, num_row_to_display, label) {

        var size_buffer = given_typed_array.length;
        var index = 0;

        console.log("__________ " + label);

        if (label === "time") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                var curr_value_time = (given_typed_array[index] / 128) - 1.0;

                console.log(curr_value_time);
            }

        } else if (label === "frequency") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                console.log(given_typed_array[index]);
            }

        } else {

            throw new Error("ERROR - must pass time or frequency");
        }
    }

    function process_microphone_buffer(event) {

        var i, N, inp, microphone_output_buffer;

        // not needed for basic feature set
        // microphone_output_buffer = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // just mono - 1 channel for now
    }

    function start_microphone(stream){

        gain_node = audioContext.createGain();
        gain_node.connect( audioContext.destination );

        microphone_stream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone_stream.connect(gain_node); 

        script_processor_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER, 1, 1);
        script_processor_node.onaudioprocess = process_microphone_buffer;

        microphone_stream.connect(script_processor_node);

        // --- enable volume control for output speakers

        document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function() {

            var curr_volume = this.value;
            gain_node.gain.value = curr_volume;

            console.log("curr_volume ", curr_volume);
        });

        // --- setup FFT

        script_processor_analysis_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        script_processor_analysis_node.connect(gain_node);

        analyser_node = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyser_node.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
        analyser_node.fftSize = 2048;

        microphone_stream.connect(analyser_node);

        analyser_node.connect(script_processor_analysis_node);

        var buffer_length = analyser_node.frequencyBinCount;

        var array_freq_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);
        var array_time_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);

        console.log("buffer_length " + buffer_length);

        script_processor_analysis_node.onaudioprocess = function() {

            // get the average for the first channel
            analyser_node.getByteFrequencyData(array_freq_domain);
            analyser_node.getByteTimeDomainData(array_time_domain);

            // draw the spectrogram
            if (microphone_stream.playbackState == microphone_stream.PLAYING_STATE) {

                show_some_data(array_freq_domain, SIZE_SHOW, "frequency");
                show_some_data(array_time_domain, SIZE_SHOW, "time"); // store this to record to aggregate buffer/file
            }
        };
    }

}(); //  webaudio_tooling_obj = function()

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Volume</p>
    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.0"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it! Just a head's up! This looks like what I wanted !

Comment: I tried your code, but this was not what I wanted. https://mozdevs.github.io/MediaRecorder-examples/record-live-audio.html